# Can not call method of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to develop a javascript object that creates a menu in html.
The function receives an object as an argument. Among the object elements is a function that should be executed in an event handler called from a method of my object.

Here is my code :

```
Menu = function(config) {
    var j = 0;
    this.config = config;
    this.make = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < this.config.items.length; i++) {
            var vid = document.createElement("div");
            vid.className = this.config.cls;
            vid.id += i;
            document.body.appendChild(vid);
            var txt = document.createTextNode(this.config.items[i]);
            var pp = document.createElement("p");
            pp.appendChild(txt);
            vid.appendChild(pp);
        }

        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.scrolldown, false);
        document.onkeydown = function(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            alert("functional");
            if (keyCode == 40) {
                alert("You hit key down");

                var et = document.getElementById(j);
                this.config.trait1(et);
                j = j + 1;
            } else {
                alert("no");
            }

        }
    };

    return this;
};
```

when I call the function make after instantiating the object I have my elements created but my event isn't handled because of :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trait1' of undefined .

Can anyone help me? I saw many answers of the same question but none of the suggested solutions worked.

Comment: Why are you mixing modern event handler binding (`document.addEventListener`) with outdated event handler binding (`document.onkeydown = function`)?

Comment: I just forgot to delete one of them. But the errors as you told me was because of 'this' not refering to my object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` inside the `Menu` function is not the same as `this` inside the `onkeydown` function.

Store the value of `this` in another variable and use that.

```
Menu = function () {
    var myMenu = this; // I'm assuming that you will be calling `new Menu()`
    document.onkeydown = function () {
        myMenu.config.etc.etc.etc
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting would also be `this.scrolldown` which is also bound to the same event.

Comment: yes for document.addEventListener("keydown", this.scrolldown, false); it is useless I forgot t o delete it. I was just trying to find out where my error is coming from ;)